# SAML ACS Assertion Consumer Service protocol

Tags: active-directory, saml

I am trying to authenticate a ruby on rails app through SAML with Azure Active Directory.

In the AD settings it is only allowing https not http URLs as the "reply url" AKA the ACS or Assertion Consumer Service.

My question is does the ACS url have to be over https, if so, is there a way to develop with an app on localhost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ADFS is somewhat specific and sometimes does not implement the SAMLv2 spec correctly (i.e. the IdP meta data has not been meta data schema compliant).

The ACS endpoint need not be secured on the transport layer, although SAMLv2 recommends this.

However as you might use a so called "frontchannel binding" (HTTP POST or HTTP redirect binding), why do you bother? The browser is doing the communiation, not the app. Only if you use a 'backchannel binding', like Artifact binding the App (acting as the SP) needs to talk to the IdP (not with the ACS in this case, but the "ArtifactResolutionService")

Answer (score 1):

For this specific issue, I always use tunnelling app  https://ngrok.com/

Install and run

ngrok http 3000

Then you can use https